# Selenium- clicking on dropdown from input and javascript field

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I am trying to select a value from a dropdown after typing in some numbers. Without clicking on the dropdown, other fields will not autofill. The dropdown is made with the following HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
    <input name="dscsaNdc" class="dscsaNdc form-control rounded-corners valid" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" maxlength="13" required="" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
    <ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" role="listbox" style="top: 34px; left: 0px; display: none;">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#" role="option">
                <strong>00310-0321-30</strong>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#" role="option">
                <strong>00310-0321-30</strong>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried using the following code to see if I can click on the li.active element of the webpage, but that has not been working.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("dscsaNdc")).sendKeys("00310-0321-30");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.active > a > strong")).click();
```

In a previous text box that had a similar setup, I got around the problem by sending the Return key to the text field, but that also does not work. I think the reason is because this text field has a character limit. Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: There are two exactly the same elements. Is that a typo?

Comment: i guess `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.active > a > strong")).click();` will just simulate a click event.  rather go for `.on('click') `whick fires up during click event.

Comment: `.on('click')` is not coming up as a selenium command for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try finding the option to click by the text and then use javaScriptExecutor to perform the click without expanding the options

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text (),'00310-0321-30')]"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click () ", element);
```

Comment: Doing that gives this error message `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html`